# PDF Thumbnails in HTML5

Tags: html, pdf, thumbnails

Can anyone suggest me how to create a PDF thumbnail which shows a miniature preview of the pdf file in html5. Something similar to the behaviour seen in Gmail while uploading pdf files.

Currently am using embed element, but it gives me unnecessary scrolls and not able to zoom in the file,which works across all browsers. If I set #zoom it works only in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/
If the thumbnails are not compatible in browsers like IE, including compatibility.js from the same library would solve the problem.

We have to create a canvas and use the library utility to get the thumbnail in the canvas.